# Impulse response rest conditions of LTI systems

Tags: continuous-signals

Why the impulse response (initial) rest conditions are taken like $h(t)=0$ and $h'(t) =1$, if the order of differential equation is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the second order LCCDE which defines the input-output relationship of a **causal & LTI** system, assuming $a_0=1$:

$$a_0 y^{''}(t) + a_1 y^{'}(t) + a_2 y(t) = x(t). \tag{1}$$

When the input is a unit-impulse, $x(t) = \delta(t)$, then the solution of the DE is $y(t) = h(t)$, which is called as the **impulse response** of the LTI system. General solution of Eq.1, makes use of a splitting of the output into a homogeneous part, $y_h(t)$, and a particular part, $y_p(t)$, whose superposition then yield $$h(t) = y_h(t) + y_p(t). \tag{2}$$

Since the **particular** input is an impulse, then the particular solution $y_p(t)$, as $t \to \infty$, is identically zero. Indeed, assuming that $y_p(t)$ includes an impulse, then on the RHS of the DE, derivatives of $\delta(t)$ should appear, but which is not balanced by the LHS of the DE, contradicting the assumption. And this will always be the case, whenever the order of LHS is higher than that of the RHS. Therefore $$h(t) = y_h(t). \tag{3}$$

For this second order DE, one needs two auxiliary (initial) conditions, derived based on the **initial-rest** property of LTI systems, yielding:
$$y_h(0) = 0 \tag{4}$$ and $$y_h^{'}(0) = 1/a_0 = 1. \tag{5}$$

Eq.4 is a direct consequence of initial-rest property, and Eq.5 can be seen by integrating both sides the DE from $t=0^{-}$ to $t=0^{+}$, with input $x(t) = \delta(t)$, and recognising that the output, $y_h(t)$, for this specific DE, cannnot contain any impulses. Hence,

$$\int_{0^{-}}^{0^{+}} \left( a_0 y_h^{''}(t) + a_1 y_h^{'}(t) + a_2 y_h(t) \right)dt = \int_{0^{-}}^{0^{+}} \delta(t) \tag{6}$$

$$a_0 \int_{0^{-}}^{0^{+}} y_h^{''}(t) dt + a_1 \int_{0^{-}}^{0^{+}} y_h^{'}(t)dt + a_2 \int_{0^{-}}^{0^{+}} y_h(t)dt = 1 \tag{7}
$$

The second and third integrals in Eq.7 vanish, since, as explained in the previous paragraphs,  their integrands do not include any impulses. But $y''(t)$ includes an impulse, and the first integral is, therefore, nonzero:

$$a_0 \int_{0^{-}}^{0^{+}} y^{''}(t) dt = a_0 \left( y_h^{'}(0^{+}) - y_h^{'}(0^{-}) \right) = 1. \tag{8}
$$
It follows again by initial-rest that $y'(0^-) = 0$, and thus we have:

$$y_h^{'}(0^{+}) =  \frac{1}{a_0}. \tag{9}$$

Since $y_h(t) = h(t)$, and since the impulses are gone, we can now replace $0^{+}$ with $0$, and then it follows that:
$$ \boxed{ h'(0) = \frac{1}{a_0} = 1 } \tag{10} $$

yielding the required initial condition for solving the LCCDDE to obtain the impulse response $h(t)$ of the associated LTI system.
Similar argumentation follows for systems of higher orders.